# Adobe code not working in GTM

Tags: javascript, analytics, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I am trying to set up basic Adobe analytics tracking via Google Tag Manager.  So far I have two tags set up, and am getting an error on the second tag.

Tag 1 with priority of 10 (hosting the s_code on google drive)

```
<script>
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript"
src="https://abcd.googledrive.com/host/efgh">
</sc'+'ript>');
</script>
```

Tag 2 with priority of 1

```
<script>
s.pageName=page.pageInfo.pageID; 
s.server=DomainName; 
s.channel=page.category.pageType; 
s.prop1=page.pageInfo.pageCategory;  
s.eVar1=user.segmentuserType;   
var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code);
</script>
```

I am not seeing any data sent to Adobe, and when I open the page using inspect am seeing the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: s is not defined(anonymous function)

Any idea what is wrong with this setup?

Comment: GTM does not guarantee order of operation even if you specify higher priority.  Having said that, did you check your net tab to see if the s_code.js file was loaded at all?  Is there any reason you can't put those into a single tag?

Comment: Did you remember to check the "support document write" checkbox ? And you shouldn't use priority, you should use tag sequencing (this makes sure the script load tag is fired before, and that the other tags in the sequence are not fired when the first tag failed).